# Program seg faults locally, but not when run remotely

Tags: ssh, segmentation-fault

I have a machine running Ubuntu 16.04. When I sit down in front of the machine, and run a certian program (Quartus prime pro 18.0) I get a segmentation fault error:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

When I ssh in remotely from a Ubuntu 18.04 machine, the same program runs with no problems.

This is a weird error for me. Has anyone seen this before, or have ideas of what might cause this?

Thanks!

Comment: When you are local, are you using a GUI terminal? or using a text only terminal (ctrl+alt+f4 etc)  There is a way to have gui terminals have a different setup to those from text-only (which as I recall was how remote ssh logins are treated) but I forget what config file was used by gui logins only.

Comment: How much RAM, how much Swap? `free -h` will show you. You need swap, start with 2x RAM.  Read most of what `man -k swap` tells you. Within 5 minutes of the fault, `journalctl --since="-5 minutes"` will show you system logs of interest.

Comment: @guiverc: When I ssh in, I use ssh -X username@hostname. When I'm local, I launch the program from the terminal. I'm not aware of the differences between a gui terminal and a text only terminal.

Comment: Could you add more logs like `strace` or `gdb` backtrace